# Modification of Sigmoid function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, logarithm, function, sigmoid-curve

I need to model my data into a function like shown in the following picture. 
But how I can do this mathematically? 
 Is there any similar function to model data that should increase on smaller values fast and converge to 1 relatively slow?

[image]

Comment: complementary log-log function might work

Comment: The sigmoid regression allows for more parameters than the usual 2. Four- to Five-parameter logistic regression seems quite common, and would be able to model that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try [the Gompertz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function)

The basic formula is $ y = e^{-e^{-x}} $ and looks like this: [image]

Keep in mind that the growth at the start is doubly exponential, whereas the decay at the end is singly exponential, which may still be too fast for your purposes (being of the same order as a logistic function).